# Cloud ML Tensorflow and Cudnn versions compatibility

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, cudnn

I would like to use Tensorflow 1.3 (and maybe 1.4) on Cloud ML. Im running jobs on multi-GPU machines on Cloud ML

I do that by specifying the tensorflow version in the setup.py as shown below:

```
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow==1.3.0']

setup(
    name='my-image-classification',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    version='1.0',
    packages=['my_image_classification',
              'my_image_classification/foo',
              'my_image_classification/bar',
              'my_image_classification/utils'],
    )
```

What is the cudnn library that is installed on Cloud ML? Is it compatible with tensorflow 1.3 and tensorflow 1.3+ ?

I was able to start the jobs, but the performance is 10X lower than the expected value, and I'm curious if there is a problem with the underlying linking of Libraries

Edit:

I'm pretty confident now that the Cudnn versions on Cloud ML dont match what is required for Tensorflow 1.3. I noticed that Tensorflow 1.3 jobs are missing the "Creating Tensorflow device (/gpu:0...) " Logs which appear when I run a job with the default available Tensorflow on cloud ml

Comment: Where you actually able to deploy a model in Cloud ML with TensorFlow r1.3? I tried that a couple of weeks ago and it wasn't possible. In fact, the supported runtime versions are r1.0 and r1.2, listed here: cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list However, I have been able to train with r1.3 with no problems, as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/versioning#specifying_custom_versions_of_tensorflow_for_training. I guess that that the nodes deployed do a standard installation of whichever REQUIRED_PACKAGES are defined in the setup.py but not for prediction.

Comment: Yes. It is still not supported as a runtime, but this is a workaround. Use the --runtime-version=HEAD command line argument to your gcloud submit job .. command. You should also specify the REQUIRED_PACKAGES in your setup.py. See comments below the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, that made it :) Thanks!
Now we can even train and deploy a model with TF 1.4 but we can't do batch predictions on it, although we can do online predictions surprisingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: using anything but 1.0, 1.2 is not officially supported as of 2017/11/01.

You need to specify the GPU-enabled version of TensorFlow:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0']
```

But the version of `pip` is out-of-date so you need to force that to update first.

Comment: This breaks my imports with the error: import tensorflow as tf
ERROR 2017-11-02 12:41:12 -0700 service  ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Comment: ah, the `pip` version is too old on the service.

Try using --runtime-version=HEAD when submitting your job. Same disclaimer applies.